# Passing String with Otto between Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, otto

I'm trying to pass String value between fragments using Otto.
It seems like `@Produce` and `.post` works well. But `@Subscribe` isn't Working...
I've registered `BusProvider` on Both Fragments. But it isn't working.
What should i do to make it work?

AppDrawerFragment.java 
https://gist.github.com/sukso96100/a636a7ead69839cfa5b6

WorkspaceFragment.java
https://gist.github.com/sukso96100/5f4fc8d3f74997d830c1

BusProvider.java
https://gist.github.com/sukso96100/733118a4c03bc5fc5d5f

AddAppShortcutToHomeEvent.java
https://gist.github.com/sukso96100/a6c09f27ec6264d5d9c4﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do

`BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);`

instead of

`BusProvider.getInstance().register(getActivity());`

to correctly register for receiving events.

And to unregister you simply do

`BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);`